# Create button which change string value every time clicked

Tags: c#

I want to create a button which will change the string value every time I click in C#.

Here is my C# code:

```
partial class Translator2 : Page
{

    public string from = "en"; // initial value
    public string to = "ja"; // initial value



    public async void Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string from1 = from;
        string to1 = to;
        string uri = "https://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate?text=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(text) + "&from=" + from1 + "&to=" + to1;


 public  void Switch(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (from == "en" & to== "ja")
        {
            from = "ja";
            to = "en";
        }
        else if(from == "ja"& to =="en")
        {
            from = "en";
           to = "ja";
        }


    }
```

If I click the switch button, the string value changed from ja and to en. However, if I click again, nothing changed. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Did you set the two texts also in the Page_Load event? Did you protect this setting under !IsPostback ?

Comment: I am not sure what page_load event is and isPostback setting. I don't setting anything.

Comment: How are the `from` and `to` fields  getting initialized? Shouldn't they be getting their initial values from the request itself?

Comment: It is `&&`, not `&`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using an `enum` for clarity.

```
public enum Language {
    En_Ja,
    Ja_En
}

Language lang = Language.En_Ja;

 public  void Switch(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     lang = lang == Language.En_Ja ? Language.Ja_En : Language.En_Ja;
 }
```

Comment: Agree, and additional to @Edwin Surya, you should use properties instead of public fields. See http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter8/PropertiesMatter.aspx for more information.

Answer (score 0):

#### Short Answer:

The `from` and `to` fields need to be initialized by the HTTP request. Something like:

```
partial class Translator : Page
{
    string from, to;

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
         var to = Context.Request.QueryString["to"];
         var from = Context.Request.QueryString["from"];

         switch(from.ToUpper())
         {
             case "EN": { this.from = "en"; break; }
             case "JA": { this.from = "ja"; break; }
         }

         switch(to.ToUpper())
         {
             case "EN": { this.to = "en"; break; }
             case "JA": { this.to = "ja"; break; }
         }

         if(to == null) throw new Exception();
         if(from == null) throw new Exception();

    }
}
```

#### Longer Answer:

This is actually a good use case for polymorphism:

```
/* C# 7 syntax */

abstract class LanguageSetting
{
    public static LanguageSetting English = JA.alt;
    public static LanguageSetting Japanese = EN.alt;        

    public abstract LanguageSetting Alternate { get; } 
    public abstract override string ToString();

    sealed class EN : LanguageSetting
    {
        public static readonly LanguageSetting alt = new JA();

        public override LanguageSetting Alternate => alt;
        public override string ToString() => "en"; 
    }

    sealed class JA : LanguageSetting
    {
        public static readonly LanguageSetting alt = new EN();

        public override LanguageSetting Alternate => alt;
        public override string ToString() => "js"; 
    }
}
```

Then your `Submit()` and `Switch` methods are simply:

```
void Submit(object Sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string from = lang.ToString();
    string to = lang.Alternate.ToString();

    string uri = "https://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate?text=" + 
                  HttpUtility.UrlEncode(text) + "&from=" + from1 + "&to=" + to1;

}
```

and

```
void Switch(object Sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lang = lang.Alternate;
}
```

Finally, we initialize with something like:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
     var from = Context.Request.QueryString["from"];

     switch(from.ToUpper())
     {
         case "EN": { lang = LanguageSetting.English; break; }
         case "JA": { lang = LanguageSetting.Japanese; break; }
     }

     if(lang == null) throw new Exception();

}
```

Comment: I disagree. I think the solution of Mr Awesome is much more readable for the given context. In the given example he only shows that he wants inversion of 'ja' and 'en'.